# JSON path expressions with reference to other node

Tags: node.js, json, path, expression, jsonpath

I want to write a JSON path expression such that it reference other node in the expression, I do not want to hardcode any value in the expression.

For e.g. consider following JSON path, I want to get "Measurement" such that "measurementID" is equal to value of "mid" node.

I can write following query but it has hardcoded "RR" value in it.

> $.myroot.measurements[?(@.measurementID == "RR" )].Measurement

Instead I want to write so that "RR" would be picked from other node. Unfortunately following expression does not work for me.

> **$.myroot.measurements[?(@.measurementID == $.myroot.mid )].Measurement**

```
{
"myroot": {
    "name": "ABC",
    "nameA1iases": [
        {
            "AliasName": "23123",
            "AliasNameTypeID": "test"
        }
    ],
    "nameTypeID": "test",
    "mid": "RR",
    "measurements": [
        {
            "Measurement": 2.62,  //-> This should be output of the JSON query
            "measurementID": "RR",
            "MeasurementPath": "demo",
            "measurementType": "TT",
            "UnitOfMeasure": "m"
        },
        
        {
            "Measurement": 40.62,
            "measurementID": "TR",
            "MeasurementPath": "demo",
            "measurementType": "T",
            "measurementUnitOfMeasure": "m"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Can someone tell me how to reference other node.

Comment: What implementation are you using? Not all features are supported by all implementations, unfortunately.  (We're working on developing a standard, though.)  Your path, however, seems correct.  Have you tried it on any online evaluators?

Comment: I want to use plain Jsonpath for above scenario, I do not want to write any code other than pure JSON path, I tried above with few online evaluator, I do not get the expected result, it gives me empty results :(

Comment: I get that you want to just use JSON Path, but you must be using some library to evaluate the path against the data.  What is that library, and which online evaluators have you looked at?

Comment: I used https://jsonpath.com/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, there is no universally JSONPath standard, and the implementation of certain features varies from library to library.

The online evaluator you used seems to use [JsonPath-Plus](https://github.com/JSONPath-Plus/JSONPath) under the hood. While this library does indeed support reference the `$` root in a comparison operation, a different syntax is required (this still does not work online but I think this is a problem of the website):

```
$.myroot.measurements[?(@.measurementID == @root.myroot.mid)].Measurement
```

If you are using the original JavaScript implementation by Stefan Goessner you can query as intended:

```
$.myroot.measurements[?(@.measurementID == $.myroot.mid)].Measurement
```

You can verify this online [here](https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/) using the Goessner tab.

Then, ensure applying the right syntax of the library used in your project.